# Lambda to connect to Redshift and query table

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I'm attempting to retrieve data from Redshift using a Lambda function in Python 3.9. I initially tried using the Glue connector, but it resulted in timeout issues. I then attempted to use Boto3 sessions, encountering the same timeout problem. When I attempted to import psycopg2, it didn't recognize the command despite adding the layer for Python 3.9.
code is here
import pandas
import redshift_connector
import boto3
#import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime
import awswrangler as wr
def lambda_handler(event, context):
session = boto3.session.Session()

```
#Define a redshift data client
redshiftDataClient = session.client('redshift-data', region_name = region_name)
#con=psycopg2.connect("dbname=dev host=redshifttest-xyz.cooqucvshoum.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com     port=5439 user=master password=secret")
#con_redshift = wr.redshift.connect("aws-sdk-pandas-redshift")
con = wr.redshift.connect("my-glue-connection")
#with con.cursor() as cursor:
#    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ep_ext.table Limit 5 ;")
#    print(cursor.fetchall())
#con.close()
df = wr.redshift.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM ep_ext.table Limit 5", con=con)
print(df)
con.close()
```

any help
thanks

I tried online help but could not find help. expect any guidness.

Comment: The timeout issues might be due to the fact that your Redshift Cluster is on a VPC and Lambda is not able to access it. You might need to have the Lambda also on the same VPC Network to be able to connect.

Comment: Lambda is having a limitation that it won't run more than 15minutes. By default lambda's default time is set to 3 seconds. You can increase it upto 15minutes. Its not ideal to use lambda to read for ETL purpose.